# pandas apply and return multiple values

Tags: pandas, apply

I have a function as below. I want to apply it over a row of a dataframe and return 2 values and then copy those 2 values in 2 columns. My both approaches fail (last 2 lines)

```
data1 = [['Alex',10,5,0],['Bob',12,4,1],['Clarke',13,6,0],['brke',15,1,0]]
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Name','Age','weight','class'],dtype=float)
#print (df)
def calculate_distance2(row):
    return pd.Series([row['Age']+row['weight'],row['Age']-row['weight']])

df5.apply(calculate_distance2, axis=1)

df5[['distance0'],['d6']]= df5.apply(calculate_distance2, axis=1)
df5['distance0'],df5['d6']= df5.apply(calculate_distance2, axis=1)

df5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
def calculate_distance2(row):
    return [row['Age']+row['weight'],row['Age']-row['weight']]
df5['distance0'],df5['d6']=calculate_distance2(df5)
df5
     Name   Age  weight  class  distance0    d6
0    Alex  10.0     5.0    0.0       15.0   5.0
1     Bob  12.0     4.0    1.0       16.0   8.0
2  Clarke  13.0     6.0    0.0       19.0   7.0
3    brke  15.0     1.0    0.0       16.0  14.0
```

Comment: without `apply` how does python understand that it needs to apply the function over each row?

Comment: @user2543622 pandas is vectorized , when you do basic calculation , it will base on the index which means you even can do , `df['distance0']=df['Age']+df['weight']`